# Recoloring MenuStrip

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, menustrip

I have a MenuStrip and I want to change it's color. So far, I have this code:

```
public class TestColorTable : ProfessionalColorTable
{
    public override Color MenuItemSelected
    {
        get{ return Color.LightGray; } // Don't mind the colors...
    }

    public override Color MenuItemBorder
    {
        get { return Color.LightGray; }
    }

    public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin
    {
        get { return Color.LightGray; }
    }

    public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd
    {
        get { return Color.LightGray; }
    }

    public override Color MenuItemPressedGradientBegin
    {
        get { return Color.DimGray; }
    }

    public override Color MenuItemPressedGradientEnd
    {
        get { return Color.DimGray; }
    }

    public override Color MenuBorder
    {
        get { return Color.LightGray; }
    }
}
```

With this code, as well as the designer, I managed to change the color of almost every element of my MenuStrip. Almost.

Here are the results:

[image]

As you can see, there are two issues: 1) The two separators and 2) That thin white border around the submenus.

Any ideas on how to change the color of those two parts of my MenuStrip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For the separator color try overriding the [`SeparatorDark`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.professionalcolortable.separatordark.aspx) and or [`SeparatorLight`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.professionalcolortable.separatorlight.aspx) property of the [`ProfessionalColorTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.ProfessionalColorTable.aspx) class.
2. As for the thin white border around the submenus..., well, its actually not a border. It's the [`ToolStripDropDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown.aspx) (the submenu) background itself. Try overriding the [`ToolStripDropDownBackground`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.professionalcolortable.toolstripdropdownbackground.aspx) property of the [`ProfessionalColorTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.ProfessionalColorTable.aspx) class to change its color.

Example:

```
public class TestColorTable : ProfessionalColorTable
{
  ...
  public override Color SeparatorDark
  {
    get { return Color.DimGray; }
  }

  public override Color ToolStripDropDownBackground
  {
    get { return Color.DimGray; }
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Excellent, except one thing: the `SeparatorDark` actually changes the separator, but it the line itself is not longer visible. Is there a way to change the color of the line and the color of the background seperately?

Comment: Actually, nevermind. I used the `SeperatorLight` instead and the line is not visible in the separator.